# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'prompt_required'

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror, traceback

When I run these statements in Jupyter notebook

```
import helics; 
import helics_cli; 
%system helics run --path=fundamental_default_runner.json
```

I get the following traceback error:

```
'Traceback (most recent call last):',

 '  File "e:\\anaconda\\lib\\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main',
 '    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,',

 '  File "e:\\anaconda\\lib\\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code',
 '    exec(code, run_globals)',
 '  File "E:\\anaconda\\Scripts\\helics.exe\\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>',
 '  File "e:\\anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\helics_cli\\cli.py", line 108, in <module>',
 '    def profile_plot(path, save, invert):',
 '  File "e:\\anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\click\\decorators.py", line 192, in decorator',
 '    _param_memo(f, OptionClass(param_decls, **option_attrs))',
 '  File "e:\\anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\click\\core.py", line 1714, in __init__',
 '    Parameter.__init__(self, param_decls, type=type, **attrs)',
 "TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'prompt_required'"
```

What is the error? Has *init*() been called without 'prompt_required'?

Which file is actually causing the error? How do I fix this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.